# SQL - DATEDIFF with a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff

I need to pass a value downstream from a `SQL Server` DB which is essentially the difference between two `timestamps`. This is simple enough with the `DATEDIFF` function.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, '2015-11-06 00:00:00.000','2015-12-25 00:00:00.000') AS DiffDate ;
```

However at the time of passing the value down the code only knows an order ID value and not the 2 time stamps shown above. Therefore I need the `timestamp` info to come from a subquery, or something else I think. The main nuts and bolts of the sub query is here:

```
select O.DATE1 , C.DATE2
from TABLE1 O, TABLE2 C
WHERE O.VALUE1_ID = C.VALUE1
AND O.order_id = '12345678'
```

I've tried a few different ways , however none have been sucesfull. The latest I've tired is below, which from a syntax perspective looks ok, but I get the error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string

which I'm never too sure how to cope or deal with.

```
select DATEDIFF (day,'(select O.VALUE1 
from TABLE1 O 
where O.VALUE1 = 16650476)' , 
               '(SELECT C.VALUE1 
                 from TABLE1 O, TABLE2 C 
                 WHERE O.VALUE1 = C.VALUE2 AND O.order_id = 12345678)') AS DIFFDATE;
```

Any pointers or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.  Your code samples really do not help convey what you are trying to do.

Comment: .. preferably by using ddl + dml statements for the sample data so that we could [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subqueries shouldn't be strings, so remove the single quotes. Also, you talk abot O.DATE1 and C.DATE2, so you probably mean something like this:

```
select DATEDIFF (day, 
              (select O.DATE1 
                 from TABLE1 O 
                where O.VALUE1 = 16650476) , 
              (SELECT C.DATE2 
                from TABLE1 O, TABLE2 C 
                WHERE O.VALUE1 = C.VALUE2 AND O.order_id = 12345678)) AS DIFFDATE;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the following:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, cj.SomeDateColumn, C.SomeDateColumn)
FROM TABLE1 O 
JOIN  TABLE2 C  ON O.VALUE1 = C.VALUE2
CROSS JOIN (SELECT O.SomeDateColumn FROM TABLE1 WHERE order_id = 16650476) cj
WHERE  O.order_id = 12345678
```

Comment: Hi All, appreciate all the feedback, sorry to some if I was not clear, Klas pointed out something that was really obvious, and it seems to have fixed my query.

Answer (score 0):

Could you Declare two variables of datetime and then datediff the two variables?

```
DECLARE @FirstDate AS datetime
DECLARE @SecondDate AS datetime
SET @FirstDate = (select O.VALUE1 from TABLE1 O where O.VALUE1 = 16650476)
SET @SecondDate = (SELECT C.VALUE1 from TABLE1 O, TABLE2 C WHERE O.VALUE1 = C.VALUE2 AND O.order_id = 12345678)
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, @FirstDate, @SecondDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the below I have used your sub query but more information on the data in the tables "Table1" and "Table2" would be useful

```
SELECT
    DATEDIFF(day, D.Date1, D.Date2) AS DiffDate 
FROM
(
    select O.DATE1 as Date1 , C.DATE2 as Date2
    from TABLE1 O, TABLE2 C
    WHERE O.VALUE1_ID = C.VALUE1
    AND O.order_id = '12345678' 
) D
```

The reason you are getting the error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string

is because you are passing strings (below) to the datediff function instead of using a date

```
'(select O.VALUE1 
from TABLE1 O 
where O.VALUE1 = 16650476)'
```